# Using Microsoft Fakes to shim SerialPort object

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017, microsoft-fakes, shim

I want to write a unit test for a class that makes calls to a `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort` object. I need to return canned/simulated data from a fake serial port. When I create a Fakes assembly for `System.dll` it generates a `System.IO.Ports.Fakes.StubSerialPort` but no `System.IO.Ports.Fakes.ShimSerialPort`. The `StubSerialPort` doesn't appear to contain many methods, mostly just constructors. I can't find any examples anywhere for doing this, so I'm posting here. I'm running VS 2017 Enterprise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft's answer [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/261616/unable-to-shim-serialport-using-microsoft-fakes.html).

For performance reasons Fakes does not generate shims for all types by default in the System/mscorlib modules. To tell it to generate shims for "System.IO.Ports" you could set the following in mscorlib.fakes and system.fakes for your project:

```
<ShimGeneration>
    <Add Namespace="System.IO.Ports!"/>
</ShimGeneration>
```